# How to change the color of children

Tags: vue.js, sass

Please tell me how to use the tools Vue.js and/or SCSS to implement logic. Depending on the level (data-level - from 1 to 6) of the children div the color changes. There is a implemented example in jQuery.

[Here Is My jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzhsqtec/9/)

```css
  .ui-core-skill {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
 }

 .ui-core-skill-name {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7px 0 0;
 }

 .ui-core-skill-level {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

 .dot-max {
     height: 9px;
     width: 9px;
     float: left;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  }

.dot-mid {
     height: 7px;
     width: 7px;
     @extend .dot-max;
 }

.dot-min {
    height: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    @extend .dot-max;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-core-skill">
<span class="ui-core-skill-name">Name</span>
 <div class="ui-core-skill-level" data-level="4">
    <div class="dot-max"></div>
    <div class="dot-mid"></div>
    <div class="dot-min">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the codes you have tried by Vue?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution with just scss would be to do something like this for each level:

```
/*Your old scss goes above here*/

.ui-core-skill-level[data-level="4"] {
   .dot{
     &-max{
        background-color: rgba(238, 122, 71, 1);
     }

     &-mid{
        background-color: rgba(238, 122, 71, 1);
     }

     &-min{
        background-color: rgba(238, 122, 71, .3);
     }
   }
}
```